# how to change or replace all column name in data table

Tags: c#, datatable

i am retrieving table from data base and storing in data table.i need to change all column name in data table how to do it....

i want to replace _ in column name 
    e.g

```
   Supplier_Name //column name from data base
   Supplier Name //i want to display like this
```

storing to data table

```
   { 
   DataTable dt= new DataTable();
   dt= table //table from data base
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the SQL statement rather than doing by coding, like below

```
select Supplier_Name as [Supplier Name] from MyTable
```

Answer (score 5):

```
dt.Columns["Supplier_Name"].Caption = "Supplier Name";
```

Or if names are dynamic:

```
foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    column.Caption = column.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ");
```

NOTE: [DataColumn.Caption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.caption%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property supposed to be used for displaying columns friendly name, but developers of DataGridView control did not respect that intent. So, in order to display this changes in DataGridView, you should set headers to captions *after* binding to table:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridColumn in dataGridView1.Columns)
     gridColumn.HeaderText = dt.Columns[gridColumn.HeaderText].Caption;
```

Comment: @Happy That still does what you want IMO

Comment: obj_dt = obj_DB_Con.connection_db(store_proc, null);
        foreach (DataColumn column in obj_dt.Columns)
                {
                    column.Caption.Replace("_", " ");
                    
                }
how to add edit column to existing datatable...
                
           return obj_dt;

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
  column.Caption.Replace("_"," "); 
  //or column.ColumnName
}
```